# how to get all possible device information in android through webview or phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

How to get all possible Android device information in Android through WebView or Phonegap

```
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;
String versionName = pinfo.versionName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By phonegap I suppose you meant by using Javascript in a phonegap app.

You have device object that stores some of the device's info.

Reference:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

If you need extra information ,it's super easy to create a phonegap plugin and do this. You just need to know how to do this in Java (native language) and send the information to the javascript running in the phonegap app.

Reference:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide